# Retrieve Parents and Child Rows In Single Row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a lot of SQL experience but this one is beyond my understanding. I have a table such as:

```
ID    NAME    PARENT_ID
1     A       0
2     B       1
3     C       1
4     D       0
5     E       4
6     F       4
7     G       4
```

And I need to write a single SQL statement that will return all the parents and their children in a single row:

```
ID    PARENT    CHILD_1     CHILD_2     CHILD_3  ...  CHILD_N
1     A         B           C
4     D         E           F           G
```

I do not know how many children each parent has before hand - it is variable.

Is there anyway to do this in a single SQL statement?

Thanks.

Comment: I recall an old thread over on AskTom that discussed it, however, keep it mind it gets VERY hard if you don't know your columns up front ;)  https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4471013000346257238

Comment: I believe you'll have to do a `PIVOT` query on a `HIERARCHICAL` query, where you use the `HIERARCHICAL` to get the `depth`, and then `PIVOT` on the depth. Much like https://community.oracle.com/thread/2211680  Either that or you'll have to get fancy with some dynamic sql in a Stored Procedure.

Comment: @ditto yea, I saw some articles on there but from what I can tell I need to know some of my data values. but I won't be knowing any of those.

Comment: Simple answer: this is impossible. In SQL (any DBMS, not just Oracle) the number of columns of a query must be known _before_ the query is executed.

Comment: Impossible?!!  No.  https://technology.amis.nl/2006/05/24/dynamic-sql-pivoting-stealing-antons-thunder/  You can use listagg too.

Comment: @knuckles thanks. but listagg puts all the values in a single column, right? i need them all in separate columns.

Comment: maybe creating a PL/SQL while loop that each iteration creates a new table adding one new column (child) until no more left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some of the very cool "dynamic pivot" PL/SQL solutions out there (which I don't recommend for production code -- they work 99% but fail for some odd-ball cases, in my experience).

Otherwise, you need to tell Oracle ahead of time which columns you expect your SQL to output.  That means, you can only do what you're looking to do if you implement a hard cap on the maximum number of child columns you'll include.

If you can live with having to do that, then this should work.  I took some guesses about how you would want it to work if your data had a hierarchy with multiple levels.  (Take a look at row "H" in the sample data and think about how you would want that displayed.)

```
WITH d AS ( 
SELECT 1 id, 'A' name, 0 parent_id
FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'B', 1
FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'C', 1
FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'D', 0
FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'E', 4
FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'F', 4
FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'G', 4
FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 'H', 7

FROM DUAL
),
h as (
select prior d.name parent, 
       level lvl,
       case when level = 1 then null else d.name end child_name, 
       case when level = 1 then null else  row_number() over ( partition by prior d.name, level order by d.name) end child_Number
from d
connect by parent_id = prior id
start with parent_id = 0 )
select * from h
pivot ( max(child_name) for (child_number) in (1 AS "CHILD_1",2 AS "CHILD_2",3 AS "CHILD_3",4 AS "CHILD_4",5 AS "CHILD_5") )
where lvl > 1
order by parent;
```

Comment: this is exactly what I needed! thank you so much. I never would have figured this out on my own. If I ever meet you in person I'll buy you all the beers you want.